# I got a error when convert swift 3 from 2.3 "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '((UIContentContainer, C ~~

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3

We have swift 2.3 projects on Xcode 8.2.1.
I had auto convert swift 3 from 2.3.

But I got Two troubles.

```
1.Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '((UIContentContainer, CGSize) -> CGSize)'
2.Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type '(UIContentContainer, CGSize) -> CGSize' and 'CGFloat'

        // GENERATE A GRID FOR BLOCKS -----------------------
    for i in 1...gridSize {
        for j in 1...gridSize {
            let _j = CGFloat(j-1)
            let _a = (view.frame.width - CGFloat(gridSize))
            let _b = (CGFloat(size) + CGFloat(padding))
            let _ab = (_a * _b)/2
            let _c = _j * (size + padding)
            let _abc = _ab + _c
            //let _x = (view.frame.width - CGFloat(gridSize) * (CGFloat(size) + CGFloat(padding)))/2 + _j * (size + padding)
            let _x = _abc
            let _y = CGFloat(rectsHeight) + CGFloat(i-1) * (size + padding)
            let r = Rectangle(type: "default", x: _x, y: _y, size: size, color: midGray, view: gameView!,real_x : _x, real_y : _y)

            rectanglesArray.append(r)
        }
    }
```

This is an Error message end product code.
let size and padding are CGFloat.

Why can't to do calculation (CGFloat(size) + CGFloat(padding))?
We had working from Swift 2.3.
But can't work with Swift 3.

Please support me All.

Thanks.

--04/22/2017 11:54 Added--
お返事をありがとうございます。

Sorry I forget detail padding.

```
// Resize views accodingly to device screen size
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 320 {
    //iPhone 4 / 5
    var size: CGFloat = 25
    blocksHeight = 380
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 23

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
    var size: CGFloat = 33
    var padding: CGFloat = 3
    blocksHeight = 520
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 28

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    var size: CGFloat = 36
    var padding: CGFloat = 4
    blocksHeight = 570
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 33

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 768 {
    // iPad
    var size: CGFloat = 55
    var padding: CGFloat = 6
    blocksHeight = 830
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 50
}
```

We checked all define padding.

[image]

Config.swift

```
/*** DO NOT EDIT THE VARIABLES BELOW ***/
var soundURL: URL?
var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0

var padding:CGFloat = 2
var size:CGFloat = 28
let gridSize = 10
var gameView:UIView?

var score = 0
var bestScore = Int()
var lastScore = Int()
var playCount = Int()
var gameEnded = false

var bounds = CGRect()
```

Changed code.
But new error...

3.Cannot assign to property: 'size' is a method

```
    // Resize views accodingly to device screen size
if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 320 {
    //iPhone 4 / 5
    size = 25
    blocksHeight = 380
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 23

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 375 {
    // iPhone 6
    size = 33
    padding = 3
    blocksHeight = 520
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 28

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 414 {
    // iPhone 6+
    size = 36
    padding = 4
    blocksHeight = 570
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 33

} else if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 768 {
    // iPad
    size = 55
    padding = 6
    blocksHeight = 830
    afterTouchSizeOffset = 50
}
```

----Solved-----

Config.swift

Befor

```
/*** DO NOT EDIT THE VARIABLES BELOW ***/
var soundURL: URL?
var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0

var padding:CGFloat = 2
var size:CGFloat = 28
```

After

```
/*** DO NOT EDIT THE VARIABLES BELOW ***/
var soundURL: URL?
var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0
```

GameBoard.swift

Befor

```
// Dimension variables
var rectsHeight = 50
var blocksHeight = 435
var rectsForDissapear = Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>()
var gridTilesAmount = Array<Int>()
var blockEndCoords : CGPoint = CGPoint()
var afterTouchSizeOffset : CGFloat = 25
var selectedBlock : Block?
var startTouchCoords : CGPoint = CGPoint()
let DeviceTest:Bool = false
let SimulatorTest:Bool = true
```

After

```
// Dimension variables
var rectsHeight = 50
var blocksHeight = 435
var rectsForDissapear = Array<Dictionary<String,Any>>()
var gridTilesAmount = Array<Int>()
var blockEndCoords : CGPoint = CGPoint()
var afterTouchSizeOffset : CGFloat = 25
var selectedBlock : Block?
var startTouchCoords : CGPoint = CGPoint()
let DeviceTest:Bool = false
let SimulatorTest:Bool = true

var padding:CGFloat = 2
var size:CGFloat = 28
```

Thanks all supporters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us your definition of padding, it should be a number, but I think the compiler thinks it is a closure. If that's not it, let's see all the definitions. Or in Xcode move your cursor over each of these after stopping on the line using a breakpoint to confirm they are the type you expect. One of them isn't...

Edit 1: You have shown places where these variables have been correctly defined.  But you've also shown code that doesn't make sense if you consider scope. Inside your first "if" statement you have the following:

```
 var size: CGFloat = 25
```

But you never do anything with it while it is in scope.  You never actually use the variable size while it is within scope (defined to be 25).

So where else do you define it?

Look at padding in the lines further down.  You define it 3 times, but never use them after you define them, and the value you assign here goes away when each gets to the closing "}".

You define padding somewhere else as well, if you're not getting compiler errors.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Added detail.

I set Number for Padding.

Why compiler thinks is a closure?

I'm confuse....

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。

We have a Configs.swift.
We define that file.

/*** DO NOT EDIT THE VARIABLES BELOW ***/
var soundURL: URL?
var soundID:SystemSoundID = 0

var padding:CGFloat = 2
var size:CGFloat = 28
let gridSize = 10
var gameView:UIView?

var score = 0
var bestScore = Int()
var lastScore = Int()
var playCount = Int()
var gameEnded = false

var bounds = CGRect()

Comment: Thanks!

'    // Resize views accodingly to device screen size
    if UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width == 320 {
        //iPhone 4 / 5
        size = 25
        blocksHeight = 380
        afterTouchSizeOffset = 23
        
    } ......

Comment: Hey I'm get build succeed!!

I will write right code.

Thanks for your sooooo kind!